# Delete all folders and files except one file with specific name using .bat

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I used the below code in .bat file in order to delete all files and folders inside “AutoCAD_Temp” except “parcel.dwg” but it didn’t work with me.

```
    @echo
set exclude=/Parcel.dwg/
for %%a in (C:\inetpub\Temp_FME\AutoCAD_Temp) do (

   if "!exclude:/%%~a/=!" equ "%exclude%" 
   (
      echo "Deleting" %%~a  
      del "%%~a"
   )
)
```

The folder Path: `C:\inetpub\Temp_FME\AutoCAD_Temp`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSM4z.jpg)

What might be the issue here?

I will be very appreciated for any help,

Lubna

Comment: This is a _lot_ simpler with PowerShell - just use `Get-ChildItem` with `-Exclude` and pipe to `Remove-Item`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one file to protect, all you need to do is to lock it

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Just to avoid having to retype paths, place info on variables
    set "folder=C:\inetpub\Temp_FME\AutoCAD_Temp"
    set "excluded=Parcel.dwg"

    rem If the excluded file exist, we will need to lock it. 
    if exist "%folder%\%excluded%" ( set lock= ^< "%excluded%" ) else ( set "lock=" )

    rem Change to requested folder, remove anything not locked and return
    pushd "%folder%" && (
        rmdir . /s /q %lock% 2>nul 
        popd 
    )
```

The reason for the file existence check is to avoid trying to lock a non existing file that will make the command fail, so, `lock` variable (holding the part of the final command that will lock the file for reading) is only defined if the file exists.

Comment: Very nice!, It can be easily extended to lock more files (not many more of course) by dynamically building a parenthesized block. `< "file1" ( < "file2" ( ... ( rd . /s )...))`. The performance gain is significant on a large directory structure. +1

Comment: it works with me like a charm :) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

use `findstr` to exclude the file from the search using `/v`

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b "C:\inetpub\Temp_FME\AutoCAD_Temp" ^| findstr /vi "Parcel.dwg"') do (
  echo "Deleting" %%~a  
  echo del "%%~a"
)
```

if you would like to predefine variables, simply:

```
@echo off
set "mypath=C:\inetpub\Temp_FME\AutoCAD_Temp"
set "exclude=Parcel.dwg"
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b "%mypath%" ^| findstr /vi "%exclude%"') do (
  echo "Deleting" %%~a  
  echo del "%%~a"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one line in PowerShell, for your consideration:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\inetpub\Temp_FME\AutoCAD_Temp\* -File -Exclude Parcel.dwg | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

(If the output is correct, remove the `-WhatIf` parameter to remove the files.)